# Tips for golfing in Smalltalk

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in [Smalltalk](http://smalltalk.gnu.org/)? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to [Smalltalk](http://smalltalk.org/) (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

> Smalltalk is a purely object-oriented language created by Alan Kay. The two links are GNU Smalltalk and a general Smalltalk page respectively. You do not have to pay attention on this "spoiler".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use the `;` operator to refer to the previous object

There is a convenient shorthand in Smalltalk used to refer to the previous object. Say we want to add 3 items to the set x.

```
x:=Set new
x add:5.x add:7.x add:'foo'
```

However, we can save a few bytes by using the ; operator:

```
x:=Set new
x add:5;add:7;add:'foo'
```